# Add network interfaces to Docker Image

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I'm searching for a way to create multiple loopbacks in my Docker Image.

On a "normal" Ubuntu I call

```sh
sudo ifconfig lo:1 10.53.0.2/16 up
sudo ifconfig lo:2 10.53.0.3/16 up
sudo ifconfig lo:3 10.53.1.1/16 up
sudo ifconfig lo:4 10.53.1.2/16 up
```

to setup my loopbacks, but *Docker* rejects the commands with this error message:

```sh
SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFNETMASK: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried creating networks with

```sh
docker network create
```

but that didn't work either

I'm running **Docker version 17.06.0-ce** and my *Base Image* is **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Maybe someone can help?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You could try this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, containers run with some limitations.

When start your container, use `--cap-add` to be able to add sub interfaces:

```
docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN
```